# Problems with sudo when deploying RVM with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, capistrano

I would like to use Capistrano to deploy my app in my server
I have the deploy.rb file with the following content:

```
set :user, "deploy"
set :use_sudo, true
set :deploy_to, "/webapps/#{application}"
#set :deploy_via, :remote_cache #Using this option avoids to do a full repository clone


#RVM
set :rvm_type, :system  #System Wide installation
set :rvm_ruby_string, 'ree@K2'
set :rvm_install_shell, :bash

before 'deploy:setup','rvm:install_rvm'
before 'deploy:setup', 'rvm:install_ruby'

# if you're still using the script/reaper helper you will need
# these http://github.com/rails/irs_process_scripts

# If you are using Passenger mod_rails uncomment this:
namespace :deploy do
   task :start do ; end
   task :stop do ; end
   task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
     run "touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
   end
 end
```

Everything works fine when i set the root user, installs RVM (system-wide installation) and even a Ruby Enterprise, but when I run **'cap deploy:setup'** setting the use_sudo option and deploy user, get this:

```
$ cap deploy:setup
  * executing `deploy:setup'
    triggering before callbacks for `deploy:setup'
  * executing `rvm:install_rvm'
  * executing "bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)"
    servers: ["myserver.com"]
Password: 
    [myserver.com] executing command
    [myserver.com] bash -c 'bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)'
*** [err :: myserver.com] bash: line 304: /usr/local/rvm/RELEASE: Permission denied
    command finished in 564ms
failed: "bash -c 'bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)'" on myserver.com
```

What I have to do to make this work? Do I have to adjust some settings in sudoers file?

Comment: Is your deploy user a sudoer?

Comment: Yes, i think was included in sudoers file

Answer (score 2):

please test with `1.1.0`:

```
gem install rvm-capistrano
```

Comment: Thanks, I already posted that issue linking to this questions. I hope they can resolve this.

Comment: Thanks,I didn't have time to test it out until today. It seem it works. But, now this time, the ruby enterprise is not installing:  `Warning:
*** [err :: myserver.com] Failed to create the file ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2012.02.tar.gz`

Comment: @ianenri open a new question with more details.